# Strip day from elasticsearch date using painless scripting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have date with this format `November 17th 2016, 12:54:29.000"` and I need to get that `17` only using painless script. Also if anyone can provide me link to painless script tutorial regarding date formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the field is mapped as `date` you can just

`doc['<field_name>'].date.dayOfMonth`.

Otherwise, you'll need to use a regular expression, something like

`/ (\d{2})/.matcher(doc['<field_name>'].value).group(1)`.

The date-based solution uses [`org.joda.time.MutableDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html). The regex one uses [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) and you have to enable regular expressions in your Elasticsearch configuration file as `script.painless.regex.enabled=on`.